# An open database for propensity score matching

Tags: propensity-scores, matching, database

I need an open biological or medical database for benchmarking methods for propensity score matching. Where can I find some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ones I guess, but the best I can recommend is the US National Inpatient Sample (NIS) or similar ones from the US Healthcare Cost and Utilization Project (HCUP).

See the web portal for additional references: https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/databases.jsp.

These databases have already been analyzed and the corresponding peer reviewed publications are available to guide you. For instance, have a look here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29575160 or here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29608938.